# Angular bootstrapping data in a script tag to a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to bootstrap data set in a view template to the assigned angular controller. Now previously I would just assign the data to a global variable and the controller can access it that way. But I don't like this! I would prefer to have it injected into the controller much like 'resolve' on angular routes injects the resolved data in to the called controller.

An example:

Here is my template retrieved from the server (test.html)

```
<script id="userData" type="application/json">
    {userId:1,username:'umair'}
</script>

<div>Hello <span ng-bind="data.username"></span>!</div>
```

the route (state)

```
.state('state', {
     url: "/test",
     templateUrl: "test.html",
     controller: "testCtrl"
})
```

The controller

```
controller("testCtrl", ["$scope", "userData", function($scope, userData){
     $scope.data = userData;
}])
```

Notice how the data in the json script block has been injected into the controller. Much like

```
.state('state', {
     url: "/test",
     templateUrl: "test.html",
     controller: "testCtrl",
     resolve: {
         userData: [function() { ... }]
     }
})
```

Would inject `userData` into the controller.

Now obviously I would only be able to do this once the view has been loaded, in which case I would probably need to listen in for an event. But not quite sure exactly how to implement this!

Comment: From what I can understand your problem my solution would be use $emit or $broadcast.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but just wanted to note that, if you're doing this from a server-side view, it's easy to inadvertently forget to protect against XSS by HTML-escaping strings being injected from the backend, since those strings are often nested inside of other data structures.  For example, `window.MY_LOCALS_FROM_BACKEND = <%- JSON.stringify(someData) %>;` if `someData` is a dictionary or array with strings inside, and one of those strings contains `</script>`, you've got a potential attack vector.  Anyways, been bitten that before myself so just mentioning it in case it helps.